# SQL query to exclude records if it matches an entry in another table (such as holiday dates)

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2005

I have two tables:

> **Application**
>   applicationid (int)
>   applicationname (varchar)
>   isavailable (bit)

and

> **Holidays**
>   applicationid (int)
>   holidaydate (datetime)

I need to get the *isavailable* flag for any given applicationname but it should only return if the day if is not a holiday.  The *isavailable* flag is independent of holidays - it is only set if there are system-wide problems, not on a set schedule.

I initially had something like:

```
select top 1 apps.isavailable
from dbo.Applications apps, dbo.Holidays hol
where apps.applicationid = hol.applicationid and
      apps.applicationname = @appname and
      ((datediff(dd,getdate(),hol.holidaydate)) != 0)
```

but that was returning records even if today was a holiday because the other holiday dates don't equal today.

I tried

```
and (CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),101)) not in (CONVERT(VARCHAR,hol.holidaydate,101))
```

(it is on SQL Server 2005, so there is no Date type so I have to convert it)

but again, it was returning records even if today was a holiday.  How can I structure this query using a "not in" or "except" clause (or something else) to only return a record if today isn't a holiday?

**Update**

I don't need a list of all applicationnames that don't have a holiday - I need a record for the specified apps.applicationname.  The answers below only return the application names that don't have a holiday on today.  The query should return the isavailable flag if it is not a holiday, or else return no records if it is a holiday.  I don't care about the other applications.

Also, what if I added a table like:

> **HoursOfOperations**
>   applicationid (int)
>   mondayopen (datetime)
>   mondayclose (datetime)
>   tuesdayopen (datetime)
>   tuesdayclose (datetime)
>   //open and close for all seven days of the week

Could I join on all three of these tables to only return a record if it is within the hours for the given day and is not a holiday?  Do I have to do this in separate queries?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

THe following query should get you a list of applications that DO NOT have a holiday defined for the CURRENT date.

```
SELECT apps.ApplicationName, apps.isavailable 
FROM dbo.Applications apps
WHERE apps.ApplicationName = @AppName
    AND NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * 
  FROM Holidays 
  WHERE ApplicationId = apps.ApplicationId
     AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,holidaydate,101)
)
```

Basically what we do is select everything where it does not have a match.

Comment: This gives all applications that don't have a holiday defined, but I need the isavailable flag for only the specified apps.applicationname. I don't want to have to iterate through the list after the query. Also, what if I have to join on another table - I can't combine the where and where not clause

Comment: Tai - just add a an additional clause.  AND apps.AppName = 'your application'.  You can add any joins needed,

Comment: I updated the example for you to show you how to limit by app name, assuming a param of @AppName

Comment: That works - thanks. Can you please edit it to include one more closing paren so someone can cut and paste it?

Comment: Tai - Sure did!  (I don't know where it went in the beginning!)

Answer (score 6):

OK, just to be different, how about something like this:

```
select apps.isavailable
from dbo.Application apps left outer join dbo.Holidays hol
    on apps.applicationid = hol.applicationid
    and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101) = convert(varchar(10),hol.holidaydate,101)
where apps.applicationname = @appname
    and hol.applicationid is null
```

Basically, you're joining the tables based on applicationid and the current date.  Since it's a left join, you'll always get all the applications that match @appname, then you just filter out any results that get a match based on the holiday date being the current date.  Assuming that applicationname is unique, you'll always get a single row where the right half of the join is null, unless the current date matches a holiday, in which case the query will return no results.

I don't know how it stacks up with the other solutions performance-wise; I believe joins are generally supposed to be faster than sub-queries, but that probably depends on a variety of factors, so YMMV.

Comment: Matt - In most cases the performance is about the same.  It looks like this user is needing just a single application, so the subquery route might be a bit faster...

Comment: Mitchel Sellers - I always thought the issue with subqueries was that they were repeated for every row, but I see what you're saying.  All I _really_ know about performance is that if it matters in a given case I should just measure it. ;)

Comment: And the "where not exists" approach is certainly more readable in any case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "WHERE NOT EXISTS":

```
SELECT *
FROM Applications a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Holidays h
    WHERE h.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID
        AND HolidayDate = cast(cast(getdate() as int) as datetime)
)
```

I'm doing the cast there to truncate the getdate() call back to just the date. Haven't tested that exact query but I think it'll do the job for you.

Comment: This has the same problem as Michael Sellers' answer - This gives all applications that don't have a holiday defined, but I need the isavailable flag for only the specified apps.applicationname.

Comment: Sorry - didn't think that would be a problem since your original query already included the test for ApplicationName = @appname. I figured you knew how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT (fields) FROM Application
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM Holidays
   WHERE ApplicationID = Application.ApplicationID
   AND DAY(getdate()) = DAY(holidaydate) 
   AND MONTH(getdate()) = MONTH(holidaydate)
   AND YEAR(getdate()) = YEAR(holidaydate)
  )
```

Of course it would be a whole lot easier and faster with SQL Server 2008's "DATE" datatype, or if you could store day, month, year in "Holidays" separately.

Marc

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.isAvailable
  FROM Application a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 0
      FROM Holidays b
     WHERE a.applicationid = b.applicationid
       AND holidaydate = $today
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
SELECT 
  Application.isavailable
FROM 
   Holidays 
RIGHT JOIN 
   Application
ON 
   Holidays.applicationid = Application.applicationid
WHERE 
  ((Application.applicationname='app1') AND 
  (((Holidays.holidaydate=CurrentDate()) AND (Holidays.applicationid Is Null)) OR 
  (holidays.holidaydate Is Null)));
```

"'app1'" should be replaced by a variable specifier and "CurrentDate()" by the system specific function to return the current date.

Cheers

/a